# Updating arraylist in Application class

Tags: android

I have created an **ArrayList** in my **Application** class :

```
package a.b.layout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Application;

public class CommonData extends Application{

    ArrayList<Item> commonList;

    public ArrayList<Item> getList()
    {
        return commonList;
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<Item> list)
    {
        commonList = list;
    }

}
```

I am adding content to this arraylist in different activites and updating it each time.

```
CommonData objCommonData = ((CommonData)this.getApplication()); 
objCommonData.commonList.addAll(viewData);     //viewData is local arraylist
```

But on doing so I get a **Null Pointer Exception**. Why is it so? Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you instantiate your `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Item> commonList = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

You cannot add data to an ArrayList that hasn't been created yet.

**EDIT**

To show John's solution (see comments), edit your class:

```
public class CommonData extends Application{
     static ArrayList<Item> commonList = new ArrayList<Item>();
}
```

Then you can do from somewhere else:

```
public void someWhereElse(){
    getApplication().commonList.add(item);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I thought. But on instantiating it, won't I loose the previous data inside the arraylist. A new instance will be created every time.

Comment: In this case, it would be better to declare a separate static class (with a static ArrayList variable) to keep track of your list.  You can also just declare a static `ArrayList` variable within your CommonData class and invoke calls via `CommonData.commonList.addAll()`, for example.  You would then not need the line `CommonData objCommonData = ((CommonData)this.getApplication()); `

Comment: I didn't clearly understood what you said. I'll really appreciate if you can put an example.(Edit your answer if possible).

Comment: @Stone, Herrmann did the honors.  It should be noted though that this only works if your Application is created as a CommonData Object.  In Android, this is not usually the case, and the above may not work.  If it does not, comment, and I'll post the different code that would do it.

Comment: Thank you both for your contribution. I implemented onCreate in application class and followed what you suggested. Things are working fine now :)